# Reading Overloading Methods

Tags: java, overloading

I saw a question online that asks if you are given the print statements,

`System.out.println(M.m(4.0, 5));`
 `System.out.println(M.m(4, 5.0));`

I understand that a double can be used as an int, so the first method will be printed. i.e `40.0`.

But for the second print statement, wouldn't the same logic be used, and the first method be printed again? Java is saying the second print statment is `60.0`.

```
public static double m(int a, int b) {
 return a * b;
}
public static double m(double a, int b) {
 return a * b * 2;
}
public static double m(double a, double b) {
 return a * b * 3;
}
```

Comment: `5*4 = 20`, not `40`. The second method is used in the first call, as it should be.

Comment: You can only widen types like `int` -> `double`, not the other way, unless you use a cast.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for the first print, the second overload will be used, because the parameter types match exactly: double and int.

For the second print, the third overload will be used, because double is not automatically promoted to int. The only method whose second parameter is promotable from double is the third overload - and that will force the first parameter to be promoted to double.

Comment: I like your explanation better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one method that accepts `double` as the second parameter, the first parameter is going to be coerced into a `double`, so it would be called as `M.m(4.0, 5.0)` instead, thus falling into the third method.